# Magenta overtones in CS 5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

This has happened a few times.  It resolves somehow...and then shows up again within weeks.  I have windows 10.  I open a file that I print several times a month of a drawing I did years ago.  It prints fine.  It looks pink.  The tools look like they have a pink edge around them.  If I go to the color picker to make a new document and want to use gray it looks lavender.  the CMYK values are correct.  It prints correctly.  But it looks lavender.  Same thing happens in photoshop. But anything else on the monitor (like screen savers, color calibration, etc.  the grays look correct.)  I have looked and looked on the internet...anything?  anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Color calibrate the monitor.

Odd pink or yellow tones are most often a result of a corrupt color profile. Recalibrating the monitor should correct the issue. Photoshop tends to show problems with a color profile much, much, more than any other part of a system.

If recalibrating doesn't help.. check the monitor cables to ensure they are connected well and in good condition.